# QOS and home networking, packet prioritization

Tags: networking, router, bandwidth, qos, fiber

I recently had a phone call with a tech rep over at Thinkorswim (a stock trading platform) who, after looking at my app usage, said that Thinkorswim was low on the QOS ladder and therefore could be experiencing delay and lag.

This got me thinking so I contacted Google Fiber (I'm on the 1G plan with tested speeds ~940d,680up) and asked if the Google Fiber Network Box has any QOS settings. It does not. I asked if QOS was implemented on the back end. They didn't know.

My home network consists of a few phones, wife's work laptop, tv and two desktop computers (one light browsing, the other running TOS mostly). I wouldn't imagine that I would be coming anywhere my bandwidth ceiling and so QOS would be a non-factor. Although I'm not not sure how to find out. A quick look at Windows 10 data usage shows TOS using 6GB over 30days. My wife has a half a dozen zoom calls a day, and a work server running.

I would like priority to go to Desktop running TOS. Assuming I'm not reaching my limit, could priority be going elsewhere and thereby creating delay and lag on my desktop? How would I find out?

...if need be I can break out the old Asus RT-AC68U and take out the Fiber Box, Google Fiber allows this now.

Comment: I think you may be persuing an untamed ornithoid without cause.... if you are concerned about latency, take wifi out of the equation on the box you are running this software on, and make sure the connection is as close to the ISP equipment as you can get. if you are really worried about QOS and latency, you should probably consider enterprise grade hardware. Ubiquity stuff is often quite affordable.

Comment: If you wanna do QoS and your Router does not support it, you have to buy a device that supports it. (for example ubiquiti edge router 4). Then you either have to replace the provider router with that one, or you set the providerrouter in bridge mode and place your router in between your network and the provider router. Then you can take advantage of the QoS capablities of the devices. Most people would be fine with a Smart Queue that makes sure, that traffic is balanced equally and no device can starve out all others by hogging bandwith.